# Golang get item per attibute phone dynamodb

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am querying a value in dynamodb but I get the error "The supplied key element does not match the schema".

```
{
  "id": {
    "S": "c8f8fd5d-a483-4a4e-8adf-75c4134678cc"
  },
  "phone": {
    "S": "+57308394111288"
  },
 }
```

Golang

```
params := &dynamodb.GetItemInput{
        Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            "phone": { // Required
                S: aws.String(phone),
            },
        },
        TableName: aws.String(TableName),
}
```

Comment: What's your primary key defined as (Partition key, [Sort key])? If id is your PK, then it wouldn't expect phone.

Comment: Hi Chris, yes is id, but i need get by phone

Comment: You'd have to do a full scan, which can be undesirable: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/dynamo-example-scan-table-item.html

Answer (score 2):

thanks per messages.solved this way

```
    filt := expression.Name("phone").Equal(expression.Value(phone))
    expr, err := expression.NewBuilder().WithFilter(filt).Build()

    params := &dynamodb.ScanInput{
        ExpressionAttributeNames:  expr.Names(),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
        FilterExpression:          expr.Filter(),
        ProjectionExpression:      expr.Projection(),
        TableName:                 aws.String(tableName),
    }
```

Comment: While this works, it will be very expensive as you add more data. It will scan every document in your Table. You should absolutely not do this on a regular basis.

You should look to use a GSI to solve this problem - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

Comment: Very good point Chris,Thanks